# mouse moves faster than tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, d3.js

I have an angular `directive` wrapped around a `D3 graph`. I have created a `tooltip` and i handle the `visibility` in `'mouseover'` and `'mouseout'` of the parent element, i also handle the tooltip `position` in `'mousemove'` so that it moves with the mouse.

The tooltip is `absolute`.

The issue is, when i move my mouse pointer fast enough, the `mouseout` event of the parent gets called , even though the mouse pointer is still within the specified area. I logged and found out , it is happening because sometimes the mouse pointer (when moving fast, the tooltip position hasn't updated so quick) hovers over the tooltip , which is absolutely positioned and not part of the parent.

This creates some difficulties as on `mouseout` of the parent element i am also changing the visibility of another element, so it gives a fluctuating/flicker kind of effect on fast mouse move.

I am not sure whether this is the expected behavior or if it is specific to D3 or angular.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6bQA8/5/

initially the `text and polylines` are shown, they would `hide` when `hovered` over any of the pie slices.
on `hover` over any of the `pie slices`, you will get a `tooltip`, if you move your `mouse`, the `tooltip` also moves, if you move your `mouse` fast enough, check the `console` and you will see `"tooltip hovered"` ,also on the UI you would see the flickering `text and polylines` which should be `visible` on `mouseout` from the slices.

In ideal case, "tooltip hovered" should never be called as the `tooltip` always updates with the `mouse` and it is not below the `pointer`.

P.S: one way to solve the problem is to add `pointer-events:none` to the tooltip or to increase the `offset` of tooltip from the pointer, but i am more interested in knowing why this happens and if this is a limitation of the framework or the browser or something wrong in the code. Also, since i am re-using the same tooltip object later for clicking purpose, so at that time i would have to remove the `pointer-events:none`, and increasing the `offset` does not look really good in the UI. Also, both these methods are actually hacks and not probably the correct solution.

Comment: You should really give us some `code` to work with, preferably even a fiddle. Also if you achieve your goal, how do you intend to close the tooltip?

Comment: @IvanModric added a fiddle. the tooltip would close on mouseout that's the right behavior , but because moving the mouse fast enough hovers on the tooltip itself, and so the mouseout is called, this is not the ideal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking a solution apart from the `pointer-events:none` i have done it this way:

```
slices.on("mouseout", function(d) {
                //return if the mouse out is triggered by the tooltip-menu
if(d3.select(d3.event.toElement).classed("tooltip_menu")){
        return;//if the to element is tooltip_menu
}
```

working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lpgqe0o/)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can not block mouse until it does all calculations and DOM manipulations, that's why, there is dealy in moving the tooltip.
In modern browsers operations happens at least with 4ms delay, as setTimeout/setInterval minimum delay is 4ms.